# String matching and store in a list with duplicates

Tags: python-3.x

How do i match the string which I already have predefined, and then extract them if they are present in the paragraph which i pass on.

PARAGRAPH : `Paragraph are the building blocks of papers. Many student define paragraph in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph`

Predefined strings: `['paragraph','building blocks', 'length', 'page', 'students']`

Output :

```
 ['paragraph', 'paragraph', 'paragraph', 'paragraph', 'paragraph', 'length', 'page', 'student' ]
```

CODE :

```
match = []
string_doob = paragraph.lower()
for i in predefined_string:
    if i in string_doob:
        match.append(i)
print(match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your predefined strings as regular expressions(See module `re`) and `re.findall` them

EDIT: without regex: iterate over your paragraph for each string and `replace` if string in paragraph until string is not in paragraph

EDIT2:

```
paragraph = "abaabbccchsjieiaaavdh"
strings = ["aa", "ab"]
strings_in_para = []
for string in strings:
    paragraph_copy = paragraph
    while string in paragraph_copy:
        paragraph_copy = paragraph_copy.replace(string, "", 1)
        strings_in_para.append(string)
```

Comment: i wanted to do without using regex

Comment: @pylearner Well then say so in your post; I edited my comment

Comment: "f string in paragraph until string is not in paragraph" can I have the code for this ?